# How to automate Profile-Guided Optimization as part of build in Visual C++?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, automation, msbuild, pgo

I want to incorporate PGO into the Visual C++ build steps in an *automated* fashion.

Specifically, I wish to be able to:

1. Select a build configuration (let's call it `Release (PGO)`)
2. Click Build Solution (or Build Project)
3. Simply wait for Visual Studio to:

   a. Build an instrumented version of my project

   b. Automatically invoke the executable with some command line (e.g. `--benchmark`) and wait for it to exit

   c. Collected the instrumentation data from that execution

   d. Build a profile-guided-optimized version of my project
4. Discover the PGO-optimized binary lying in my output directory

Is such a thing possible, and if so, how do I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your requirement, please check whether the target section is what you want:

[MSBuild targets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-targets?view=vs-2022)

And the time of the targets' trigger:

[Target build order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/target-build-order?view=vs-2022)

You can put the automatic steps in a script, and use exec to run it:

[Exec task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/exec-task?view=vs-2022)

Such as:

```
  <Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="xxx" />
  </Target>
```

Comment: Sounds like I have to basically script it by hand, then shove the script into the build process like any other script? i.e. there's no real support for it, I have to plumb it manually. I guess that answers my question, thanks.

Comment: @user541686 This way should be suitable for your situation and there should have no built-in Visual Studio feature for your requirements. By the way, you need to know that if you don't directly put the script file to run, for example, if you run a command, you need to make sure the command meets the XML format requirement. Such as, double quotes should be &quot; . :)